# Angular 7 only visible rows of paginated data table of angular material 6 are exported instead of the whole array using xlsx library

Tags: angular, datatable, angular7, angular-material-6, js-xlsx

I need to export an angular material data table into excel file, using `xlsx` library.

The issue is that, if I am using pagination within the data table, and on export, only the visible rows are exported:

```
exportTable()
  {
    //let data = Object.values(this.dataSource);
    const ws: xlsx.WorkSheet=xlsx.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement);
    const wb: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Data Export');

    /* save to file */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'ExportAllData.xlsx');
  }
```

I tried to export it using `json_to_sheet()`:

```
  exportTable()
  {
    let data = this.allData;
    const ws: xlsx.WorkSheet=xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    const wb: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Data Export');

    /* save to file */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'ExportAllData.xlsx');
  }
```

But the header is now indexes instead of field titles.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcgzme) describing the issue.

Should I use the second method by adding a header row to the array using `.push()` and then download it ? Or is it better to use `ng-table-export` library ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using options parameter of json_to_sheet function;

```
let options:JSON2SheetOpts  = {header: ['Name', 'Surname', 'Age']};
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, options);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Data Export');
XLSX.writeFile(wb, excelFileName + '.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
exportexcel(): void {
    /* list object is passed over here */
    const result = this.companyList.map((x) => ({
        // ColumnName: x.data,
        COMPANY_ID: x.COMPANY_ID,
        COMPANY_EMAIL:  x.COMPANY_EMAIL, 
        COMPANY_NAME: x.COMPANY_NAME,
        ADDRESS: x.ADDRESS,
        COMPANY_CONTACT: x.COMPANY_CONTACT,
    }));

    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(result);
    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
}
```