# Angular 7 and xlsx library how to export array with field name instead of index

Tags: arrays, angular, angular7, js-xlsx

Following on this question on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882108/angular-7-only-visible-rows-of-paginated-data-table-of-angular-material-6-are-ex), and this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcgzme), it seems that the material table does not fully exported to excel if the pagination is not showing all data.

So instead, I will export the array as a whole, but the problem is that the main field names is showing the indexes instead of the names:

So instead of:

```
exportTable()
{
  //let data = Object.values(this.dataSource);
  const ws: xlsx.WorkSheet=xlsx.utils.table_to_sheet(data);
  const wb: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Ind. Searched Data Export');

  /* save to file */
  xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'ExportAllData_Ind.xlsx');
}
```

I changed to:

```
exportTable()
{
  let data = Object.values(this.dataSource);
  const ws: xlsx.WorkSheet=xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
  const wb: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Ind. Searched Data Export');

  /* save to file */
  xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'ExportAllData_Ind.xlsx');
}
```

The problem is that the exported excel is setting the field names into indexes and then add at the end, the real field names:

[image]

I know it is something related to arrays, but how can I export the array with only the field name part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found my own solution, until the problem of extracting an angular material data table is fixed as it's only extracting the active pagination sheet instead of all table. I just used the traditional method:

```
exportTable()
  {
    let newArray:any[]=[];
    let data = Object.values(this.allsearched);
      Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index)=>{
        newArray.push({
          'Ind. ID': data[key].individual_id,
          'HH ID': data[key].hh_id,
          'Name(en)': data[key].ind_first_name_en+' '+data[key].ind_last_name_en,
          'Name(ar)': data[key].ind_first_name_ar+' '+data[key].ind_last_name_ar,
          'UID': data[key].uId,
          'Gender': data[key].ind_gender,
          'D.O.B': data[key].dob,
          'Head Of HH': data[key].head_of_hh,
          'Phone Number': data[key].phone,
          'Status': data[key].ind_status,
          'User ID': data[key].user_id
        })
      })


    const ws: xlsx.WorkSheet=xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(newArray);
    const wb: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'All Ind. Searched Data Export');

    /* save to file */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'ExportAllData_Ind.xlsx');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of @alim1990's answer. #typeScript

```
  exportXlsxFromErray(erray: any, fileName: string, sheetName: string) {
    let newArray:any[]=[];
    let data: any[] = Object.values(erray);
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key: any)=>{
      var headers = Object.keys(data[key]);
      // if you want to exclude a column, replace the previous line with the following line:
      // var headers = Object.keys(data[key]).filter(x => x != 'nameOfColumnToBeExcluded');
      var obj = {} as any;
      headers.forEach((header: string) => {
        obj[header] = data[key][header];
      })
      newArray.push(obj)
    })
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(newArray);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName);

    fileName += '.xlsx';
    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).